# importing system name,system current date,time in hive table

Tags: sql, linux, hadoop, hive

I want to create a table sample and it should have 9 columns and the data which I am loading has only 6 columns.I want to add my Linux system name, Linux current system date, Linux current time into my first three columns and then load the rest of the data into their respective columns.Then my final table should look like this.could anyone help me, please
NOTE: Here the sys_name|sys_date|sys_time| columns data is imported from the Linux system and for the rest of the column's data is from actual data from data set.

```
select * from sample;

sys_name|sys_date|sys_time|column4|column5|column6|column7|column8|column9|
linux   2017-03-09 21:00 data4   data5    data6   data7  data8     data9
linux   2017-03-09 22:00 data4,4 data5,5  data6,6 data7,7 data8,8  data9,9
```

Comment: will you please explain your question in detail?..i mean first time when you load data at that time you will have 6 columns and when you second time load it then you should have 9 columns..right?

Comment: Are you going to manually type sys_name|sys_date|sys_time values or are you taking it from somewhere?

Comment: I will add the columns but the data need to be loaded by taking my linux terminal time and date

Comment: What about sys_name?

Comment: My terminal name

Answer (score 0):

Use `Alter table` to add columns in your `#sample`

```
 ALTER TABLE #sample ADD sys_name VARCHAR(20) NULL, sys_date Date,some_name varchar(20) NULL;
```

Comment: This does not answer the question

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have the columns from column4 to column9 in a separate table (If not, create an external table on top of the data) in that case, you can hardcode the first three columns in a select statment and load the data into your new table using the below "insert using select " statement

```
create table sample(
sysname string,
sysdate date,
some_name string,
column4 string,
.
.
column9 string)
rowfromat delimited
fields terminated by '|'
stored as textfile;

Insert into table sample select 'linux' as sysname, date(current_timestamp) as sys_date, 'name' as some_name, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9 from original_table
```